# How to add core data classes to a framework in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, xcode4.2

I am trying to create a framework out of my existing codebase for the purpose of reuse. I have a `exmaple.xcdatamodeld` class which in turn contains some core data classes. I have added this entire `exmaple.xcdatamodeld` class into my new framework. But i am getting an error which says that some of the classes in my `exmaple.xcdatamodeld` are missing. (Example:`classname.h file not found`). Am i doing something wrong while adding the entire core data class? Can anyone help me out with my problem...

I have taken [this link as a reference](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/#list_contents) while creating the framework

edit : I am not getting the option of adding all the core data classes individually. It seems i can add only the complete datamodel file. PLease refer the screenshot below. [image]

Answer (score 3):

`exmaple.xcdatamodeld` is your data model. If it refers to any classes that you've created (which will be subclasses of NSManagedObject), you'll need to include the source files (.h/.m files) for those classes in your framework.

Comment: thanks for the info caleb. I tried to do that same thing before posting the question but i could not do it because of the problem mentioned above. Kindly refer my updated question for the screenshot. Can you please tell me what is wrong with me in this context and how can i add all the classes in the datamodel individually to the framework.

Comment: Your picture shows the interface for adding files to a target. It sounds like you need to first add the files to your project. Use the File->Add Files... command, or drag the files from the Finder into the project navigator. When you add the files the project, you'll be able to select the targets that you want to add them to, or you can add them to the targets Compile Sources section at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

The `.xcdatamodeld` file is just the model, a serialized version of the `NSManagedObjectModel`. It does not contain any classes.